# Anybody know a good PowerPc Reference text?

Tags: cpu-architecture, powerpc

I'm specifically looking for an architecture overview and how the PowerPc handles activation frames and procedure calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the [PowerPC compiler writer's guide](https://www-01.ibm.com/chips/techlib/techlib.nsf/techdocs/852569B20050FF7785256996007558C6)

Comment: You can find PDF docs on freescale.com, "Programming Environments Manual for 32-Bit Implementations of the PowerPC™ Architecture".